# How to test updates for your own app (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone

I hope you are doing well during these times.

I am paying someone to develope my iOS app. Now the app is in the app store and of course I installed it on my iPhone because I want to use it.

Now I have some updates whishes and my developer did what I ask for. But how can I test my update?

When I try to install the updated app version from his link it tells me, that I have to remove the original app from the app store first.

My developer says there is no other way then to buy a second iPhone for testing.

Do you guys have any tip for me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t see why your developer ask you to buy a new iPhone, you can use your iPhone just delete the old app and you will be able to install the new updated app.

Consider using TestFlight to test your app before submitting it to the store. TestFlight when ever there's a new build you will receive a notifications and update the app from the testFlight app easily.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't want to delete the app because I am using the app on a daily basis. I don't want to remove the app everytime I want to test a new update

Comment: so that's easy just ask your developer to change the app bundle id and you will be able to use both app on your iPhone, he may need to create a new listing on app store which he can use just to upload to testflight with this new bundle ID

Comment: If your developer uses TestFlight then the test version will be installed over the top of your current version. You data will be retained. This will also be a good test of what your users will experience when they upgrade. You can't have the released and a test version installed at the same time unless you have a testing bundle

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes he can have both but the test version should have it's own unique bundle identifier and own listing on the app store (will not be released but just used to upload the build with this different App ID) actually it's not a good practice, a good practice is to use an platform like app center to do those testing, but still a solution if he wants to use testflight any way